# socket.io with express slows down after amount of request from react client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have built a React app that is connected to a local running express node server with socket.io. Everything works fine but after a few hours of 100+ sending requests, and listening to those changes from the local server to the client it starts to slow down and won't work as efficiently until I reload the client window sessions.

I have a very difficult time troubleshooting this. Do you think it has something to do with my node server setup, or is it something with my client? Or maybe it's hardware issues? One thing I notice is that how my client keeps connecting to socket.io from the console.

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

// localhost port
const port = 4001

const app = express()

// server instance
const server = http.createServer(app)

// creates socket
const io = socketIO(server)


io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('change view', (view) => {
    console.log('view changed to: ', view)
    io.sockets.emit('change view', view)
  })

})

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

React app client side:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    socket.on('change view', (col) => {
         callAfunctionThatDoesSomething(col);
    })
  };
```

When I  send changes to the server

```
  send = () => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
    socket.emit('change view', this.state.view);
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to socket.io two times. First at **componentDidMount** and second, when calling **send()**. Which is not recommended.

You should connect to socket one time. You can connect in componentDidMount method of a component. But if you want to use socket in multiple component. This will also connect to socket multiple time.

I will say you connect to socket one time when registering routes or your whole app. I created a sample app before. You can check it.

https://github.com/vkasraj/random.ly